# Can one GPU mine on Mac OS X using cgminer?

Tags: cgminer, mac, gpu, gpu-mining

I succesfully installed [cgminer](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer) on my mac but every time I try to run it I get the message

```
[2013-09-16 15:03:49] clDevicesNum returned error, no GPUs usable
```

why is this? Is it that you cannot mine with the GPU on a mac, or am I just doing something wrong?

**Specs:**

- Macbook Pro (2011)
- Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5
- Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That generation of Intel integrated graphics does not have OpenCL support, which is needed for mining.

Comment: well that sucks, but thanks. Here is [proof](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033757.htm) for what your saying.